# Why my PC isn't detecting the right sound frequency?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, audio-processing

I'm developing a real-time sound spectrum analyzer application on Linux in c++ and i'm using FFT to calculate the magnitudes. The app gets sound from a simple cheap microphone, connected to the PC.

I tried testing the app using online sound generators by simply playing the generated sound on the speakers and i've noticed that it always shows half of the frequency of the sound played. E.g. if i generate 440Hz sound, it detects it as ~220Hz.

At first i thought that i just made some wrong calculations, but then i tried testing with other applications that can measure frequency (e.g. gtkguitune). And i noticed the same thing! Even those apps will always show only ~half of the Hz of the actual sound that's being generated on the speakers.

Does anyone have any explanation why could that be?

Comment: What is your sampling frequency for your FFT?

Comment: Quickly scanning through the question, the words "frequency" and "half" make me think of [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) in terms of sampling, but I'm not sure this is the issue though. Might be worth sharing your implementation in terms of sampling from the mic, then performing the FFT

Comment: @paisanco my sound sample rate is 44100, my FFT sample rate is 1470 (44100 / 1470 = 30 i.e. i am doing FFT 30 times in a second). I'm really new to audio processing and DSP in general, so i have no clue if this is too much/too less etc.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza yeah, but the weird thing is that it's not just my app, if you read my post above you'll see that it happens in other apps as well..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like it could be stereo samples interpreted as mono.